# Is it possible to have two separate iteration schedules with a single Azure DevOps project?

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I have a devops project with two teams operating on two-week sprints. I'd like to offset the sprints by a week and thus need separate iterations e.g.

Team A sprint 1 start 2020-10-01; Team A sprint 2 start 2020-10-15
Team B sprint 1 start 2020-10-08; Team B sprint 2 start 2020-10-22

Can anyone tell me if this is even possible and if so, how I achieve it.

Reading the Azure docs would suggest it is possible, but I can't quite work it out. I can see how I can select a different sprint from Team A's sprint dates but I don't see how I can create a separate (new) sprint date sequence 1 offset by one week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely do this. You can easily configure multiple teams in a single Azure DevOps project, and each team can have separate iteration hierarchies to organize sprints under.

While you may not create an additional "root" iteration node, there's nothing that prevents you from creating two child nodes, representing the product iteration default backlog for each team, with child nodes further underneath for each individual team sprint. This is, in fact, the recommended way to handle large organizations who use the [One Project, Many Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops) approach.

Example with the dates you mentioned:
[image: IterationsPerTeamExample]

Comment: thanks for providing a viable answer to this! Been a long wait :D

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have two separate iteration schedules with a single
> Azure DevOps project?

For this issue, I am afraid this is currently impossible to achieve. In the Project configuration page, we can see that we can only create a new child under an iteration schedule, and cannot create a separate iteration schedule.

[image]

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Thanks Hugh, but I don't think this actually addresses my issue. this seems to give me the ability to select a different sprint start date from th eoriginal date list. I've updated the question in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: If so , I am afraid this is currently impossible to achieve, you can submit a feature request on our uservoice site. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I'll add it as suggested